# how to refreshing 3d view in java?

Tags: java, swing, applet

```
private HomePieceOfFurniture adjustPieceOfFurnitureElevation(HomePieceOfFurniture piece) {

 // Search if another piece at floor level contains the given piece to elevate it at its height
  if (!piece.isDoorOrWindow()
      && piece.getElevation() == 0) {


    float [][] piecePoints = piece.getPoints();
    HomePieceOfFurniture highestSurroundingPiece = null;
    float highestElevation = Float.MIN_VALUE;
    for (HomePieceOfFurniture homePiece : this.home.getFurniture()) {
          if (homePiece != piece 
          && !homePiece.isDoorOrWindow()
          && isPieceOfFurnitureVisibleAtSelectedLevel(homePiece)) {

         Shape shape = getPath(homePiece.getPoints());
             boolean surroundingPieceContainsPiece = true;

             for (float [] point : piecePoints) {

               if (!shape.contains(point [0], point [1])) {
                 surroundingPieceContainsPiece = false;
                 break;
               }
             } 

        if (surroundingPieceContainsPiece) {
          float elevation = homePiece.getElevation() + homePiece.getHeight();

          //pravin
            if (elevation > highestElevation) {

            try{

               HomePieceOfFurniture table=homePiece;

               HomePieceOfFurniture newpiece=piece;

              if(table.getName().contains("able"))
               {
                if(newpiece.isunfolded()|| newpiece.isfolded())
                    {

                               FurnitureCatalog catalog1=preferences.getFurnitureCatalog();
                               FurnitureCategory category1=catalog1.getCategories().get(0);
                               CatalogPieceOfFurniture piece2= category1.getFurniture().get(6);
                               HomePieceOfFurniture piece3=createHomePieceOfFurniture(piece2);

                               float h=(float)piece3.getHeight();
                               float w=(float)piece3.getWidth();
                               float d=(float)piece3.getDepth();

                                  FinalHeight=h;
                                  FinalWidth=w;
                                  FinalDepth=d;

                              Content newModel= piece3.getModel();
                              String name=piece3.getName();
                              Content icon=piece3.getIcon();
                              String id=piece3.getCatalogId();

                              newpiece.setModel(newModel);
                              newpiece.setName(name);
                              newpiece.setIcon(icon);

                             // newpiece.setId(id);

                              newpiece.setHeight(FinalHeight);
                              newpiece.setWidth(FinalWidth);
                              newpiece.setDepth(FinalDepth);
                              newpiece.setFolded(true);
                              newpiece.setunFolded(false);

                    twoDView.setBackground(Color.decode(ConstantColorsFonts.ButtonNotClicked));

                  }

             }

            if (table.getName().contains("anger"))
              {

                if(newpiece.isfolded()|| newpiece.isunfolded())

                    {
                       FurnitureCatalog catalog1=preferences.getFurnitureCatalog();
                        //List<HomePieceOfFurniture> m1 = this.home.getFurniture();
                        FurnitureCategory category1=catalog1.getCategories().get(0);
                        CatalogPieceOfFurniture piece2= category1.getFurniture().get(4);
                        HomePieceOfFurniture piece3=createHomePieceOfFurniture(piece2);

                        float h=(float)piece3.getHeight();
                        float w=(float)piece3.getWidth();
                        float d=(float)piece3.getDepth();
                        float e=(float)piece3.getElevation();

                        FinalHeight=h;
                        FinalWidth=w;
                        FinalDepth=d;

                        Content newModel=piece3.getModel();
                        String name=piece3.getName();
                        Content icon=piece3.getIcon();
                        String id=piece3.getCatalogId();

                        newpiece.setModel(newModel);
                        newpiece.setName(name);
                        newpiece.setIcon(icon);
                        newpiece.setHeight(FinalHeight);
                        newpiece.setWidth(FinalWidth);
                        newpiece.setDepth(FinalDepth);

                         elevation=elevation-FinalHeight;

                         newpiece.setFolded(false);
                         newpiece.setunFolded(true);

                         new HomePane();
                   }

           }

          if(FinalHeight!=0 && FinalDepth!=0 && FinalWidth!=0) 
          {

                            newpiece.setHeight(FinalHeight);
                            newpiece.setWidth(FinalWidth);
                            newpiece.setDepth(FinalDepth);
           }
       } 

          catch(Exception ex)
               {
                     JFrame j10 =new JFrame("catch");
                     j10.setVisible(true);
                     j10.setSize(200,200);
                     JLabel op5= new JLabel(" Exception"+ex.toString());
                     j10.add(op5);

               }


                highestElevation = elevation;
                highestSurroundingPiece = homePiece;

              }

            }

          }

        }

      if (highestSurroundingPiece != null) {
      piece.setElevation(highestElevation);
      return highestSurroundingPiece;

    }

  }
```

this is my code which working properly... but having problem in refershing in 3d view ... please help me out(in 3d view model is not changing!!)

Comment: That's a lot of code ! Maybe you should try to isolate the relevant part...

Comment: ... that seems to be missing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101738/how-to-refreshing-3d-view-in-java, will u plz tell me how to refersh the 3d view?? is there any predefined method ???